# My program works in ModelSim, but doesn't work on real FPGA board

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim

There is my [VHDL code](http://pastebin.com/R5Wv0XJN), and there is [BDF desing](http://i50.tinypic.com/2yubuh4.jpg).

When I simulate my VHDL code in ModelSim, it's working fine, but when I simulate it in Quartus or upload to FPGA Cyclone board, LED have no signal. IDK, in what way I suppose to look at.

Comment: Have you tried uploading a sanity check sort of simple VHDL code to your board? Does the Cyclone board come with a test bit-stream to verify basic operation?

Comment: Do you mean that Cyclone doesn't work? Its university desks(>10), and my program doesn't work in Quartus simulation too.

Comment: Have you first done a design flashing one LED on and off slowly?  That's only a dozen lines of code, and until you have that working and understand how you got it that way, there's a big jump from "it works in simulation" to "it works on the chip"

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin I do not know if your board works or not. I am suggesting, along with Martin, that you start off with a small test to be certain you can successfully download a bitstream to the board, that the board works and so on. Walk up the mountain a step at a time instead of leaping from the ground to the top in one step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a quick look at your code, and while it seems syntactically correct, it doesn't really look synthesizable (even though it may be).

For example:

```
led_size : process(clk, size)
begin
  if size = '1' then     
    led_size_f <= led_size_f +1;
  end if;
  if  led_size_f > 4 then 
    led_size_f <=1;
  end if;
end process;
```

It doesn't even use `clk`, and it will also generate a latch (generally a bad thing, unless you're absolutely certain what you're doing), which will most probably give you problems when trying to run it in an FPGA.

I can post more examples, but if I were you, I'd try looking at the list of warnings that you're most probably getting from your synthesis tool.

Also, see if your IDE comes with some templates for synchronous design, and then try to adhere to them, to make sure that you are actually inferring the hardware that you want.

Comment: So, I delete clk where I don't use it, and compilate program, and see `Warning: LATCH primitive "knight_rider2:inst|led3" is permanently disabled`. Maybe it means, that I somewhere forget something?

Comment: `Info: Pin "LEDR[0]" has no specified output pin load capacitance -- assuming default load capacitance of 0 pF for timing analysis`

Comment: It's about more than just removing 'clk' from where it isn't used - you need to "Think Hardware" (tm) when doing VHDL development. Your code needs to synthesized and mapped to hardware that is available in your FPGA device, and this is far from possible with all the syntactically correct VHDL you can write. As said, you need to adhere to some specific templates, to make your code map correctly to hardware. A good VHDL book can help you with this - and the help function in your IDE can possibly also.